# Android Studio: "Prefix key pressed: Toggle Logcat Formatting"

Tags: android, android-studio

This morning I updated Android Studio to Electric Eel.
I'm using Mac with Ventura.

Currently I'm not able anymore to create @ characters. Normally done with Alt-key and L-key. On the status-bar on the button appears a message "Prefix key pressed: Toggle Locat Formatting"

[image: Status Bar]

**What's going wrong here? How can it be fixed?**

Has it to do with the update? I guess so. I haven't had that before.

Comment: I got the same issue, can not write code annotation anymore, very annoying. I also try to find out whether there is anything in keymap overload the key combination "alt" + "L" at AS Electric Eel for M1 mac, but didn't see anything in Keymap settings so far.

Comment: The logcat has "Alt" + "L" reserved, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/263475910, it is literal stopping us from coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a temporal fix for this.

1. In Android Studio -> preferences -> keymap -> Plugins -> Android -> Toggle Locat Formatting
2. Right mouse click -> remove

[image]